# format lookupset expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In Report Builder, I have an expression using the lookupset function that pulls back either nothing, a date and description, or several dates and several descriptions.  The data it is pulling is correct. I have searched this forum and MSDN.  Using what I've found in both places, I have tweaked my expression to the following.

My expression:

```
=Join(Lookupset(Fields!ProjectName.Value,
                Fields!ProjectNames.Value,
                Fields!TaskBaseline0FinishDate.Value & " - " & Fields!TaskName.Value, 
                "DsActivitiesCompleted"))
```

However, when this is displayed it doesn't have a carriage return, it just puts one after another after another.  Example Below:

[image: example of how it currently looks]

> 08/05/2015 – Milestone: Kickoff meeting Complete 08/18/2015 – Milestone: PMT Test Planning Complete 08/26/2015 – Milestone: Set CCD Date 08/26/2015 – Sprint 0 Complete 09/18/2015 – Milestone: Wave 1 Complete 09/28/2015 - Milestone: Wave 2 Complete

What I want it to look like is below. If possible I would like to have bullet points in front of each line as well.

[image: Example of how it should look]

My question is how do I get it in the format above?

Thanks,
MM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the final (optional) argument of [JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h(v=vs.90).aspx) which states which character you want to use to join your string together.  Changing your expression tyo use `vbCrLf` (the VB new line code) as follows

```
=Join(Lookupset(Fields!ProjectName.Value,
            Fields!ProjectNames.Value,
            Fields!TaskBaseline0FinishDate.Value & " - " & Fields!TaskName.Value, 
            "DsActivitiesCompleted"),
            vbCrLf)
```

Gives this output

[image]

**Update**

Use the below to use Chr(183) as a bullet character for each new line as well

```
=" " + Chr(183) + " " + 
 Join(Lookupset(Fields!ProjectName.Value,
            Fields!ProjectNames.Value,
            Fields!TaskBaseline0FinishDate.Value & " - " & Fields!TaskName.Value, 
            "DsActivitiesCompleted"),
            vbCrLf + " " + Chr(183) + " ")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That worked perfectly.  I had gotten to the point of figuring out the VbCrLf or Chr(13) & Chr(10) which both do the same thing but hadn't been able to find the bullet point part.  Thank you again Jonnus!  :-)

Comment: One thing I am noticing now is that when there is no data to return it still puts a bullet point.  I'd rather it not put anything or some specific wording if there is nothing to display.  Suggestion on how to make that happen?

Comment: Put an iif round that first line to only put a bullet when there is data