# Report Builder 3.0 indicators

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have an expression that I got help with on here.  This is the link: [format lookupset expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160759/format-lookupset-expression)

Now, I've been asked to put indicators instead of bullet points in front of each line.

Below is the criteria for the indicators.  I do have this data in my dataset to use.

Red indicator (diamond shape) = Issues with Priority of 4 OR Resolution Due Date more than 5 days late.

Yellow indicator (triangle shape) = Issues with Priority of 3 OR Resolution Due Date between 1 and 5 days late.

What I would like to see on one line is an indicator based on the criteria above, then the date, then the description. Next line is another indicator, date, description etc.

Currently this is what my expression look like:

```
=" " + Chr(183) + " " + 
 Join(Lookupset(Fields!ProjectName.Value,
            Fields!ProjectName.Value,
            Fields!DUEDATE.Value & " - " & 
 Fields!Title.Value, "Ds2MinIssues"),
            vbCrLf + " " + Chr(183) + " ")
```

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To use indicators in this way you will need to break the single textbox into a number of items within the single cell.

I would suggest using a Tablix to achieve the desired result.

1. Create your tablix
2. Set Column 1 to be the Date for the items
3. Right Click the Row, select Add Group -> Row Group - Parent Group and select ProjectName.
4. In the first empty column then right click the Data cell, and select Insert -> Rectangle
5. Right click this same cell and select Insert -> Text box
6. Right Click the Text box and select Expression..., and enter the expression

   ```
   =Fields!TaskBaseline0FinishDate.Value
   ```
7. Then type `-` in the text box and the right click it and select Create Placeholder...
8. Set this placeholder to be Value to be

   ```
   =Fields!TaskName.Value
   ```
9. Finally, right click a clear area in the rectangle and select Insert -> Indicator, and set up the indicator as required.

This results in the design

[image]

Using this dataset

```
ProjectName  TaskBaseline0FinishDate  TaskName  
-----------  -----------------------  --------
A            08/05/2015               Milestone: Kickoff meeting Complete
A            08/18/2015               Milestone: PMT Test Planning Complete
A            08/26/2015               Milestone: Set CCD Date
A            08/26/2015               Sprint 0 Complete
A            09/18/2015               Milestone: Wave 1 Complete
A            09/28/2015               Milestone: Wave 2 Complete
```

Results in this output

[image]

You can then play with this output to hide or rename columns you don't need, format the output as required, and set the indicator to report on the new fields correctly.

Hopefully this will set you on the right path to achieving the desired outcome.  Please let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: With your info, I've made some progress but I don't think this quiet gets me where I need to be with this report.  So, if you will look at my previous post that you helped me with, I'm using the lookupset function to pull in data based on a project name.  I still need it to pull data the same way because I have multiple datasets.  These indicators should be dynamic and match with the data that I'm pulling.  I wish I could post more than 2 pics/links to give a clearer understanding of the challenge I'm facing.  Any further feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered combining the datasets so that you can have all the data to hand without having to refer to second dataset?  I'm not sure you re going to be able to have everything you want with your current data structure.

Comment: Is there an easy way to combine the datasets?

Comment: If you're using Stored Procedures then you can create a table variable with all your potential columns, and insert each sub-dataset into that to return a single dataset you can then query.

Comment: This report was already built and I'm just changing a portion of it.  The datasets that were already there are stored procedures that I don't have access to.  So I had to add datasets to get the data I needed to change the portion of the report I've been asking questions about.

Comment: So, it sounds like building the report from scratch with my own datasets built the way I want them is the best possible answer.